# alguien sabe por que no me da la suma ni el promedio?

Tags: c#, array

```
using System;

namespace tarea1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int [] numero;
            int suma = 0, par = 2; double prom;
            numero = new int[30];

            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                numero [i] = par;
                suma += numero[i];
                par += 2;
            }

            prom = suma / 30;

            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(numero [30- i - 1] );

            Console.WriteLine("sumatoria: ",suma);
            Console.WriteLine("promedio: ", prom);
            Console.ReadKey();   
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu ejercicio corregido quedaría:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //declaramos las variables enteras y double para el promedio
        int suma = 0, par = 2; double prom;
        //declarmos el array
        int[] numero = new int[30];
        //bucle para dar valores al array
        for (int i = 0; i < numero.Length; i++)
        {
            //almacenamos en la primera posición del array el valor de la variable entera par
            numero[i] = par;
            //acumulamos el valor del contenido del array en la variable suma
            suma += numero[i];
            //aumentamos el valor de la variable par en 2
            par += 2;
        }
        //calculamos el promedio dividiendo la suma de los valores del array entre la longitud del array
        prom = suma / numero.Length;

        Console.WriteLine("----------------------");
        //bucle para imprimir los valores del array menos el último término del mismo
        for (int i = 0; i < numero.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            //vamos imprimiendo los valores y una coma salvo el número del array
            Console.Write(numero[i] + ", ");
        }
        //imprimimos ahora la última posición del array
        Console.WriteLine(numero[numero.Length - 1]);
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------");
        //mostramos la suma de los valores del array
        Console.WriteLine("sumatoria: " + suma);
        //mostramos el cálculo del promedio
        Console.WriteLine("promedio: " + prom);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Esta instrucción asi:

```
Console.WriteLine("sumatoria: ",suma);
```

No hace absolutamente nada. Fíjate en la documentación de la [función](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_) (lo que es siempre muy importante).

Tu `string`, debe especificar en que lugar imprimir el objeto que le pasas.

Podrías hacerlo por ejemplo asi:

```
Console.WriteLine("sumatoria: {0}",suma);
```

Donde {0} es el lugar donde queres imprimir el parámetro objeto pasado a la función.

Answer (score 4):

Si quieres puedes darle solución a tu problema usando **Linq**, de esta forma el código quedará más compacto, legible y fácil de mantener:

```
int[] numeros = new int[30];
int par = 2;

for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
   numeros[i] = par;
   par += 2;
}

var suma = numeros.Sum();
var promedio = numeros.Average();

foreach(var n in numeros.Reverse())
{
   Console.WriteLine(n.ToString());
}

Console.WriteLine("Sumatoria: {0}", suma);
Console.WriteLine("Promedio: {0}", promedio);
```

Se llena el arreglo de números como lo haces hasta ahora y posteriormente usas los **métodos** **Sum** y **Average** para calcular la suma y el promedio de los números de la colección.

Después usas un **ciclo foreach** para imprimir todos los elementos del arreglo, y para asegurar que la impresión se haga al revés se usa el **método** **Reverse**, invirtiendo de esta forma el orden de los elementos de la colección.

Posteriormente imprimirías la suma y el promedio calculado.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```